# How to set focus on an Input field in a sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: sapui5

I want to set the focus on a input field in a row in the table. How can I read the Id of this row and set the focus?

```
for(var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

   var oEntry = this.getView().getModel("items").getProperty(
   oTable.getContextByIndex(i).sPath);

   if (oEntry.Field1 === sField1){
      //Here I will set the focus in an Input field
   }
}
```

Thanks

Edit:

```
<columns>
    <Column width="2rem" sortProperty="Field">
        <m:Label text="{i18n>Field}" />
        <template>
            <m:CheckBox
                selected="{
                path: 'items>Field',
                type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String'
                }"
            editable="false" />
        </template>
    </Column>
    <Column width="6rem">
        <m:Label text="{i18n>Field1}" />
        <template>
            <m:Text text="{items>Field1}" />
        </template>
    </Column>
    <Column width="6rem">
        <m:Label text="{i18n>Field2}" />
        <template>
            <m:Input
                value="{items>Field2}" />
        </template>
    </Column>
```

This are the columns of my table in the view: I want to get the focus on the line, where Field1 = s.Field1. How can I set the id in a special line ?

Edit 2.0:

XML View:

```
<Column width="6rem">
    <m:Label text="{i18n>Field2}" />
    <template>
        <m:Input
            id="input2" value="{items>Field2}"/>
    </template>
</Column>
```

Controller:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var oEntry = this.getView().getModel("items").getProperty(
                              oTable.getContextByIndex(i).sPath);
    if (oEntry.Field1 === sField1){
        this.getView().byId("input2").focus();

     }
}
this.getView().getModel("items").refresh(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could do something like following:

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("idTable");
var aRows = oTable.getRows();
for (var i = 0; i < aRows.length; i++) {
    if (aRows[i].getBindingContext().getObject().Field1 === sField1) {
        var oCell = aRows[i].getCells()[2]; // select 3rd cell
        oCell.focus(); // focus on the Input field
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the view through its ID and then use the `focus()` function to set the focus to it.

For example,

```
var oInput = new sap.m.Input({id: "inputID"})
.addEventDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: function(){
        oInput.focus();
    }
});
```

or if your input has an id, say "input1" then you can do this

```
this.getView().byId("input1").focus();
```

EDIT:
Assuming input is the element you want to ID then it's simple to do so,

```
<Column width="6rem">
    <m:Label text="{i18n>Field2}" />
    <template>
        <m:Input
            value="{items>Field2}"
            id="input1" />
    </template>
</Column>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can i choose the correct line in the table ?

Comment: give an ID to the input row you want to access and you can find it in any line of code using the `.byId("your ID here")` method. You should first get a reference to the current view, probably using `this.getView()`. check my edit above

Comment: Thanks, I edit the post with some more details. Where can I set the id in a row ?

Comment: I use the ID, but the cursor does not focus on the Input field. Is there something, I have to do to get the correct row of the table ? Or do you know a method to get for example the fourth row on the top ( first place )

Comment: Can you show the updated XML and the part in your code where you set focus?

Comment: I don't know what your if statement is doing, but can you try putting an alert or console.log message inside the if statement to see if the condition is ever met? `alert("condition met");` would work.

Comment: the condition is met and the alert pop up. If I set the focus on an Input field outside the table it works, but not inside the table

Comment: Do you know a solution ? Thanks